# In Symfony2 and FOSUserBundle, override the login_check

Tags: php, security, symfony, fosuserbundle

In the moment that the user is authenticated, I need to check his role to redirect him to the correct page (two different pages for two different roles).

I haven't found in the documentation how to override the login_check. Right from the bundle, it uses the security.yml configuration proxy to tell the engine to go to one unique default page. Any clue?

The same problem for logout.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you want to redirect freshly logged in/logged out user to appropriate route
depending on its role?

[**Here**](http://www.reecefowell.com/2011/10/26/redirecting-on-loginlogout-in-symfony2-using-loginhandlers/) is a tutorial on how to do redirection on login/logout using form handlers.

Comment: Dustin Dobervic's post gives 404 :(

Comment: Excellent thing! I didn't know about the LoginHandlers to be in control of the response after a successful login. Thanks for a helping article.